# Suppose that a functionis continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ \c and that $\lim_ {x\to c} f'(x)$ exists. Prove f is differentiable at $c$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus{c}$ and that $\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$ exists. Prove using the mean value theorem that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and that $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x) = f(c)$.

My thoughts so far:

Consider $f$ restricted to $[a,b]$ with $a<c<b$ then by the MVT,$\exists\alpha,\beta\in (a,b)$ s.t.

$$f'(\alpha) = \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}, f'(\beta) = \frac{f(b)-f(c)}{b-c}$$

Can I go anywhere from here, or do I need to apply the MVT in another way?

Comment: For each $c<x$ there is some $c<d_x<x$ such that $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(d_x)$. Use the definition of a limit to deduce that $\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists and equals $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$. A similar proof works for the limit when $x\to c^-$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $f'\left(x\right)\to A$ as $x\to c$. Then for any positive $\epsilon $, there will be a positive $\delta$ such that
$$0<\left|x-c\right|<\delta$$
implies that
$$\left|f'\left(x\right)-A\right|<\epsilon. $$
Note that for such $x\neq c$, we have
$$ \frac{f\left(c\right)-f\left(x\right)}{c-x}=f'\left(\alpha_x\right)$$
for an $\alpha_x$ between $x$ and $c$. Then since
$$\left|\alpha_x-c\right|<\left|x-c\right|<\delta,$$
we have
$$\left|\frac{f\left(c\right)-f\left(x\right)}{c-x}-A\right|<\epsilon.$$
Then the proposition follows from the definition of a derivative.